# Problem assigning a value to an "adjacent" variable

Tags: c++

Here in this code, I have first described int a and assigned value 9 to it and then I declared another int b and then I have given value 3 to *(&b-1)  so (&b-1) refers to &a and then I printed the value of a then it prints 9 only but when I add new line in the code(line no. 6) i.e. first printed a and then assigned value 3 to (&b-1) then it updates a to 3 and prints it. So why it's happening like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double a, b;
    a = 9;
    //cout<<&a<<" "<<a << endl ;
    *(&b - 1) = 3;
    cout << a << " " << &b - 1 << " ";
    cout << &a;
}
```

Comment: `*(&b - 1) = 3;` is undefined behavior.  Whatever the code does isn't guaranteed.

Comment: In you code, a and b are double, not int.

Comment: What is the purpose of the program? Why did you write it? Or if you didn't write it, where did you find it?

Comment: "_so (&b-1) refers to &a_" No, it doesn't. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't do stuff like this. Maybe you should learn about references ...

Comment: Please improve the title though. "C++ program concept" does not at all describe your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry for that I will take care next time.

Comment: Take care _this_ time and edit the title please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so (&b-1) refers to &a

No, that's not how C++ works.

You can't "navigate" the stack frame like this, because C++ is an abstraction and does not have stack frames.

What you're doing here is pretending that `b` is a pointer to the second (or later) element of an array, and trying to get the value of the preceding element in that array. As we know, you do not actually have an array.

> So why it's happening like this?

That's why. You lied to the compiler, and now it's freaking out.

Yes, it really does care about this kind of thing!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is based on a false premise

> [...]  (&b-1) refers to &a [...]

Thats wrong. So when you ...

```
*(&b - 1) = 3;
```

you are dereferencing a pointer that you are not allowed to dereference. There is no `double` stored at `(&b - 1)`. As this is undefined behaviour your program can do anything and thats about as much as one can say about your code ;).